# table or view does not exist in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, wicket

I am getting below error while application is start

```
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

ERROR org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle - Can't instantiate page using constructor public com.bt.capman.web.admin.page.AdminPage()
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor public com.bt.capman.web.admin.page.AdminPage()
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:168)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:262)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:283)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:210)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:91)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1175)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1252)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1353)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:493)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:355)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:124)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.bt.capman.web.filter.ContextAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(ContextAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:149)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2029)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2024)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:283)
    at com.bt.capman.dao.network.interconnection.exception.ExceptionDAOHibernate.getdata(ExceptionDAOHibernate.java:40)
```

I have checked the code at ExceptionDAOHibernate.java:40

```
List<ExceptionView> list = crit.list();
```

and ExceptionView is refer a View which is accessible in DB. I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Could be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that you are trying to get some data from table which you have no access to reach. Check if you are logged in with proper user or if this user has all privileges.

Comment: I have already cross checked the DB crendiatila are same as in HIbernate config and sql developer properties file

Answer (score 0):

Also check connection user's **SELECT** rights on the **SEQUENCE** used for that table, if you're working with **Oracle DB**..